# GASでGeolocation APIを使おうとするとReferenceError: navigator is not definedと出る

Tags: google-apps-script, webapi

現在地を取得したいです。そのためGeolocation APIを用いて、[こちら](https://github.com/w3c/geolocation-api)を見ながら以下のようなコードをgsファイルに書いたのですが`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`と出てしまいました。これは何かgsファイルにUrlFetchApp()のようなのでAPIのエンドポイント(?)を記述しなくてはいけないということでしょうか？

```
function geoFindUser() {
      //getCurrentPositionメソッドで現在地を取得
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
              function(position) {
                //データを変数にして整理（position.coords.latitude/longitudeが座標）
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                Logger.log(lat,lng);
              }  
          )
  }
```

Comment: navigator.geolocationはWebブラウザで利用できるAPIのはずですが、今回はGASでやりたいということですか？

Comment: さようでございます。どうやったらGASでも利用できますでしょうか？